# Accessing a table column that is not in my domain model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my domain model *RestaurantOwner* I have added `public List<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }`. This created a *RestaurantOwnerId* column in my *Restaurants* table. When trying to access that table in code, I can access all the properties of my *Restaurant* table, except for *RestaurantOwnerId* of course, because that is not in my *Restaurant* domain model.

I thought it was obvious and that I could just add *RestaurantOwnerId* as a prop to my *Restaurant* domain model but it seems to change a lot more and mess with my foreign keys.

What's the clean way to access this column?

Thanks!

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class RestaurantOwner : IdentityUser
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public List<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the lack of information. The models are fairly simple, I use EF Code First, indeed. I edited the post. I want to access "RestaurantOwnerId" in my "Restaurants" table, but since the column is generated because of ```public List<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }```, I can't access it using ```_dbContext.Restaurants.Add(new Restaurant {...});``` in my service. What I'm trying to achieve is that the logged in RestaurantOwner his ID is added to that column when the restaurant is created.

Comment: Perhaps expand on "but it seems to change a lot more and mess with my foreign keys." with an example of what you tried, and how it was messing things up. Since RestaurantOwner is an IdentityUser you probably would want to avoid adding a navigation property to in in Restaurant, but simply having a Property for the FK in that entity should be perfectly fine. (Loading the Owner separately by ID in the event that you need info from it, or using an explicit `Join`)

Answer (score 1):

Best thing you can do is try to remove existing relationship and add the relationship again properly. To remove the relationship, remove `public List<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }` from `RestaurantOwner`. Then create a migration.

Afterwords create the relationship again as follows. (There are many conventions when using efcore for one-to-many relationships, this is one of them. What you have followed is another convention. Take a [look](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx).)

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string RestaurantOwnerId { get; set; }
    public RestaurantOwner RestaurantOwner { get; set; }
}

public class RestaurantOwner : IdentityUser
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a migration and update the database. Make sure to configure referential action constraint using Fluent API through the `OnDelete` method which takes a `DeleteBehaviour` enumeration. The following example sets the foreign key value of the dependent entity to null in the event that the principal is deleted:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(Modelbuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<RestaurantOwner>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Restaurants)
        .WithOne(e => e.RestaurantOwner).
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
}
```